# Firefox tool for finding difference in HTML before and after AJAX response?

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firebug

I want to inspect a page that is using AJAX requests for making some slight changes to the HTML. The source is huge and the AJAX response is not JSON/XML but 1000 lines of JavaScript code, which manipulates the DOM.

There is Firediff, but it seems to only work with an outdated version of Firebug. What other tools are there for me to inspect the differences in HTML code before and after an AJAX call?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is copy the HTML before and after modifications and compare results.

To copy the HTML:

- go to the 'Elements' tab,
- right click on the `body` tag and choose "Copy",
- pase result somewhere safe.
- Repeat after modification.

To compare gathered results, you can use online tool [diffchecker.com](https://www.diffchecker.com/) or console tool `diff` (linux / OS X).

---

Alternatively, you can use an extension like [DOMListener](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/domlistener/jlfdgnlpibogjanomigieemaembjeolj) that lists all DOM changes in the console.